# Velas con matplotlib muy finas en python

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]MI problema es que me muestra las velas muy finas y no se distinguen bien, me gustaria se vean mas normales, aca dejo el codigo y una captura, los datos de los precios los saco de binance, las xxx son las key y secretkey que otorga binance

```
client = Client('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
velas = client.get_historical_klines("BTCUSDT", Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_15MINUTE, "10 hour ago UTC")



ohlc_data = []

for x in velas:

    ohlc_data.append((x[0],float(x[1]),float(x[4]),float(x[2]),float(x[3])))



plt.style.use("dark_background")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
candlestick_ochl(ax, ohlc_data, width=100,colorup=u'blue', colordown=u'yellow', alpha=1.0,)
plt.xticks(rotation = 30)
ax.autoscale_view()

plt.xlabel('Hora')
plt.ylabel('Precios')
plt.title('BTCUSDT 15 MINUTOS')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El ancho del rectángulo de las velas se controla mediante el argumento `width`, al cual asignas en tu caso un valor de 100. La documentación dice al respecto:

> **width** : float, fraction of a day for the rectangle width
>
> **width** : float, fracción de un día para el ancho del rectángulo

Realmente el rectángulo de la vela se genera con el siguiente código:

```
OFFSET = width / 2.0

rect = Rectangle(
    xy=(t - OFFSET, lower),
    width=width,
    height=height,
    facecolor=color,
    edgecolor=color,
)
```

dónde `t` es el tiempo.

El problema es que, como vemos, ese valor solo indica el ancho del rectángulo en unidades del eje `x`. Por defecto tiene un valor de 0.2, este valor es más que suficiente en casos normales en los que el eje `x` representa días, por ejemplo, moviéndonos dentro del rango de decenas o centenas.

En tu caso, **tienes unos valores muy grandes para el eje `x`**, si te fijas en la parte inferior derecha de la gráfica, vemos que aparece `10e7 + 1.557e12`, esto  nos indica que de `38.0` es realmente 1557375000000,  `38.5` es 1557385000000, etc. El ancho que les asignas, 100, es un ancho muy pequeño para esa escala.

Podemos reproducir tu ejemplo usando una lista de datos inventados:

```
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ochl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


ohlc_data = [ (38.0*10**7+1.557*10**12, 28.799, 29.799, 27.799, 30.799),
              (38.1*10**7+1.557*10**12, 29.959, 30.9809, 28.712, 31.999),
              (38.2*10**7+1.557*10**12, 28.799, 29.979, 27.709, 30.999),
              (38.3*10**7+1.557*10**12, 28.959, 30.1808, 27.712, 31.143),
              (38.4*10**7+1.557*10**12, 29.959, 28.1808, 30.712, 27.783),
              (38.5*10**7+1.557*10**12, 29.759, 31.1808, 29.002, 31.553),
              (38.6*10**7+1.557*10**12, 28.954, 29.1808, 28.112, 30.455),
              (38.7*10**7+1.557*10**12, 28.659, 29.3808, 28.001, 30.223),
              (38.8*10**7+1.557*10**12, 28.959, 30.8808, 27.712, 31.143),
              (38.9*10**7+1.557*10**12, 30.959, 28.1808, 31.712, 27.143),
              (39.0*10**7+1.557*10**12, 28.799, 29.799, 27.799, 30.799),
              (39.1*10**7+1.557*10**12, 29.959, 30.9809, 28.712, 31.999),
              (39.2*10**7+1.557*10**12, 28.799, 29.979, 27.709, 30.999),
              (39.3*10**7+1.557*10**12, 28.959, 30.1808, 27.712, 31.143),
              (39.4*10**7+1.557*10**12, 29.959, 28.1808, 30.712, 27.783),
              (39.5*10**7+1.557*10**12, 29.759, 31.1808, 29.002, 31.553),
              (39.6*10**7+1.557*10**12, 28.954, 29.1808, 28.112, 30.455),
              (39.7*10**7+1.557*10**12, 28.659, 29.3808, 28.001, 30.223),
              (39.8*10**7+1.557*10**12, 28.959, 30.8808, 27.712, 31.143),
              (39.9*10**7+1.557*10**12, 30.959, 28.1808, 31.712, 27.143),
              (40.0*10**7+1.557*10**12, 28.799, 29.799, 27.799, 30.799),
              (40.1*10**7+1.557*10**12, 29.959, 30.9809, 28.712, 31.999),
              (40.2*10**7+1.557*10**12, 28.799, 29.979, 27.709, 30.999),
              (40.3*10**7+1.557*10**12, 28.959, 30.1808, 27.712, 31.143),
              (40.4*10**7+1.557*10**12, 29.959, 28.1808, 30.712, 27.783),
              (40.5*10**7+1.557*10**12, 29.759, 31.1808, 29.002, 31.553),
              (40.6*10**7+1.557*10**12, 28.954, 29.1808, 28.112, 30.455),
              (40.7*10**7+1.557*10**12, 28.659, 29.3808, 28.001, 30.223),
              (40.8*10**7+1.557*10**12, 28.959, 30.8808, 27.712, 31.143),
              (40.9*10**7+1.557*10**12, 30.959, 28.1808, 31.712, 27.143),
              (41.0*10**7+1.557*10**12, 28.799, 29.799, 27.799, 30.799),
              (41.1*10**7+1.557*10**12, 29.959, 30.9809, 28.712, 31.999),
              (41.2*10**7+1.557*10**12, 28.799, 29.979, 27.709, 30.999),
              (41.3*10**7+1.557*10**12, 28.959, 30.1808, 27.712, 31.143),
              (41.4*10**7+1.557*10**12, 29.959, 28.1808, 30.712, 27.783),
              (41.5*10**7+1.557*10**12, 29.759, 31.1808, 29.002, 31.553),
              ]


plt.style.use("dark_background")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
candlestick_ochl(ax, ohlc_data,
                 colorup='blue',
                 colordown='yellow',
                 alpha=1.0,
                 width=100
                 )

plt.xticks(rotation=30)
ax.autoscale_view()

plt.xlabel('Hora')
plt.ylabel('Precios')
plt.title('BTCUSDT 15 MINUTOS')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')
xticks = plt.gca().get_xticklabels()

plt.show()
```

Lo que nos muestra una gráfica con la misma escala para el eje `x` que tu caso y, por tanto, con el mismo problema que comentas:

[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes simplemente subir el valor, para este ejemplo, valores entre 200000 y 500000 dejan ver los cuadrados sin llegar a solaparse.

```
candlestick_ochl(ax, ohlc_data,
                 colorup='blue',
                 colordown='yellow',
                 alpha=1.0,
                 width=400000
                 )
```

[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se desea, es posible ampliar el ancho de las líneas también, usando el retorno de `candlestick_och`, que es una tupla de la forma:

```
(
     [matplotlib.lines.Line2D, matplotlib.lines.Line2D, ...],
     [matplotlib.patches.Rectangle, matplotlib.patches.Rectangle, ... ]
)
```

por lo que podemos acceder tanto al rectángulo como a la línea posteriormente  modificar sus propiedades:

```
candeles = candlestick_ochl(ax, ohlc_data,
                            colorup='blue',
                            colordown='yellow',
                            alpha=1.0,
                            width=400000
                            )


for candel_line in candeles[0]:
    candel_line.set_linewidth(5)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]